# Is it wrong to use an exact differential instead of an inexact differential?

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, notation

I encountered two equations that should describe the same thing:
$$dU=\delta Q-\delta W$$
and
$$dU=dQ-dW$$
Is it necessary to write e.g. $\delta Q$ instead of $dQ$?

$U$ denotes internal energy, $Q$ denotes heat and $W$ denotes work.

Comment: As long as you and those you are trying to communicate with know what you mean then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Necessary *for what*?

Comment: Only the difference between $\delta Q$ and $\delta W$ is an exact differential.  Individually, they are not exact differentials, even for reversible paths.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Necessary for the equation to be true.

Comment: See the first comment for the answer to that.

Comment: Some people denote all inexact differentials with a delta, some use a d with a bar through it, some just use a d.

Comment: Other people (Planck included) preferred to avoid to speak of differentials at all writing just $Q$ insted of $dQ$, $\delta Q$ and alike. I think this is probably the best notation.

Answer (score 0):

The use of exact and inexact differentials in thermodynamics are to tell you whether the the function is path independent or not. Thus it's not completely necessary to use the different differentials, as long as you (and everyone going to use/read your work) know which functions are dependant on the path and which ones are not.